# How to fix this 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope

Tags: javascript, mern

This project is based on MERN stack and jsx file shows the error 'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

I tried to regenerate code but still its throw error I expect to get advise to fix this error.